# How can I provide additional user's data on login (CAS)

Tags: spring-security, single-sign-on, cas, shiro

Is it possible to provide additional user’s data (like email) to clients?

My CAS server gets full about user from its data source. After client application logged in I have only user name. How can I transfer user’s info from CAS server app to CAS client app?

Suppose I can implement RESTful service that will be called after login by CAS client app but how can I secure it?

Comment: could you explain your question with a little bit more detail, please?

Comment: I have found very similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882298/getting-more-attributes-from-cas-than-just-user-id

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your authentication source (AD, LDAP, etc) you could configure CAS to return the extra attributes you want to the client. This is achieved using the attribute repository by the jasig persondir API. Using a special validation filter, you could then return extra attribute such as email, etc and have them be available inside the Principal object.

See this link for more info plz:
https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Attributes