# Cas 3.5.2 audit failed

Tags: spring, cas, shiro

I am a new-hander to cas. 
I download cas-server-3.5.2 and cas-client-3.2.1,then I deploy the cas server to tomcat 6 and 7.
I change the configuration in deployementConfig.xml and some other file to disable ssl and enable mysql db.
when I open the cas server page: http:// pc-name:8080/cas/login, I can **sigin on correct**.
but when I want to sign onto http:// pc-name:8080/cas/services. it always prompt **access denied:UsernameNotFoundException::y2**

Then I integrate the cas to my Java webapp with shiro-cas. It can be redirected to the login page as following

http:// pc-name:8080/cas/login?service=http:// pc-name:8080/grsp/shiro-cas 
but it display as following in cosole and be redirected to error page been fixed up.

```
2013-05-19 17:09:30,443 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] -<org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler successfully authenticated [username: y2]>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,458 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <Resolved principal y2>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,458 INFO [org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl] - <org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler@13abee1 authenticated y2 with credential [username: y2].>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,458 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] -    <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: y2]
WHAT: supplied credentials: [username: y2]
ACTION: AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sun May 19 17:09:30 CST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,458 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] -    <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: [username: y2]
WHAT: TGT-4-B0Zkj9xcuURQmKIRvdb1UGbpKiqZtZP7f0SxAmotRDEYfaGieO-yeyz-pc
ACTION: TICKET_GRANTING_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sun May 19 17:09:30 CST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,458 INFO [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <Granted service ticket [ST-7-9c3DcdatknxA0fc1ZF6d-yeyz-pc] for service [http:// yeyz-pc:8080/grsp/shiro-cas] for user [y2]>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,458 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] -    <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: y2
WHAT: ST-7-9c3DcdatknxA0fc1ZF6d-yeyz-pc for http:// yeyz-pc:8080/grsp/shiro-cas
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_CREATED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sun May 19 17:09:30 CST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,522 ERROR [org.jasig.cas.CentralAuthenticationServiceImpl] - <ServiceTicket [ST-7-9c3DcdatknxA0fc1ZF6d-yeyz-pc] with service [http://yeyz-pc:8080/grsp/shiro-cas does not match supplied service [http:// yeyc-pc:8080/grsp/shiro-cas]>
2013-05-19 17:09:30,522 INFO [com.github.inspektr.audit.support.Slf4jLoggingAuditTrailManager] -    <Audit trail record BEGIN
=============================================================
WHO: audit:unknown
WHAT: ST-7-9c3DcdatknxA0fc1ZF6d-yeyz-pc
ACTION: SERVICE_TICKET_VALIDATE_FAILED
APPLICATION: CAS
WHEN: Sun May 19 17:09:30 CST 2013
CLIENT IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
SERVER IP ADDRESS: 127.0.0.1
=============================================================

>
```

my deployerConfigContext.xml is as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--

Licensed to Jasig under one or more contributor license
agreements. See the NOTICE file distributed with this work
for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
Jasig licenses this file to you under the Apache License,
Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file
except in compliance with the License.  You may obtain a
copy of the License at the following location:

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.

-->
<!--
| deployerConfigContext.xml centralizes into one file some of the declarative configuration that
| all CAS deployers will need to modify.
|
| This file declares some of the Spring-managed JavaBeans that make up a CAS deployment.  
| The beans declared in this file are instantiated at context initialization time by the Spring 
| ContextLoaderListener declared in web.xml.  It finds this file because this
| file is among those declared in the context parameter "contextConfigLocation".
|
| By far the most common change you will need to make in this file is to change the last bean
| declaration to replace the default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler with
| one implementing your approach for authenticating usernames and passwords.
+-->

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
<!--
    | This bean declares our AuthenticationManager.  The CentralAuthenticationService service bean
    | declared in applicationContext.xml picks up this AuthenticationManager by reference to its id, 
    | "authenticationManager".  Most deployers will be able to use the default AuthenticationManager
    | implementation and so do not need to change the class of this bean.  We include the whole
    | AuthenticationManager here in the userConfigContext.xml so that you can see the things you will
    | need to change in context.
    +-->
<bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.AuthenticationManagerImpl">

    <!-- Uncomment the metadata populator to allow clearpass to capture and cache the password
         This switch effectively will turn on clearpass.
    <property name="authenticationMetaDataPopulators">
       <list>
          <bean class="org.jasig.cas.extension.clearpass.CacheCredentialsMetaDataPopulator">
             <constructor-arg index="0" ref="credentialsCache" />
          </bean>
       </list>
    </property>
     -->

    <!--
        | This is the List of CredentialToPrincipalResolvers that identify what Principal is trying to authenticate.
        | The AuthenticationManagerImpl considers them in order, finding a CredentialToPrincipalResolver which 
        | supports the presented credentials.
        |
        | AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers for two purposes.  First, it uses them to identify the Principal
        | attempting to authenticate to CAS /login .  In the default configuration, it is the DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver
        | that fills this role.  If you are using some other kind of credentials than UsernamePasswordCredentials, you will need to replace
        | DefaultCredentialsToPrincipalResolver with a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the credentials you are
        | using.
        |
        | Second, AuthenticationManagerImpl uses these resolvers to identify a service requesting a proxy granting ticket. 
        | In the default configuration, it is the HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver that serves this purpose. 
        | You will need to change this list if you are identifying services by something more or other than their callback URL.
        +-->
    <property name="credentialsToPrincipalResolvers">
        <list>
            <!--
                | UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports the UsernamePasswordCredentials that we use for /login 
                | by default and produces SimplePrincipal instances conveying the username from the credentials.
                | 
                | If you've changed your LoginFormAction to use credentials other than UsernamePasswordCredentials then you will also
                | need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations) to declare a CredentialsToPrincipalResolver that supports the
                | Credentials you are using.
                +-->
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.UsernamePasswordCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" >
                <property name="attributeRepository" ref="attributeRepository" />
            </bean>
            <!--
                | HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver supports HttpBasedCredentials.  It supports the CAS 2.0 approach of
                | authenticating services by SSL callback, extracting the callback URL from the Credentials and representing it as a
                | SimpleService identified by that callback URL.
                |
                | If you are representing services by something more or other than an HTTPS URL whereat they are able to
                | receive a proxy callback, you will need to change this bean declaration (or add additional declarations).
                +-->
            <bean
                class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.principal.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsToPrincipalResolver" />
        </list>
    </property>

    <!--
        | Whereas CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identify who it is some Credentials might authenticate, 
        | AuthenticationHandlers actually authenticate credentials.  Here we declare the AuthenticationHandlers that
        | authenticate the Principals that the CredentialsToPrincipalResolvers identified.  CAS will try these handlers in turn
        | until it finds one that both supports the Credentials presented and succeeds in authenticating.
        +-->
    <property name="authenticationHandlers">
        <list>
            <!--
                | This is the authentication handler that authenticates services by means of callback via SSL, thereby validating
                | a server side SSL certificate.
                +-->
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.HttpBasedServiceCredentialsAuthenticationHandler"
                p:httpClient-ref="httpClient" p:requireSecure="false" />
            <!--
                | This is the authentication handler declaration that every CAS deployer will need to change before deploying CAS 
                | into production.  The default SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler authenticates UsernamePasswordCredentials
                | where the username equals the password.  You will need to replace this with an AuthenticationHandler that implements your
                | local authentication strategy.  You might accomplish this by coding a new such handler and declaring
                | edu.someschool.its.cas.MySpecialHandler here, or you might use one of the handlers provided in the adaptors modules.
                +-->
            <!-- yyz comment it.
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.support.SimpleTestUsernamePasswordAuthenticationHandler" />
            -->
            <bean class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler">
               <property name="dataSource" ref="casDataSource" />
               <property name="sql" value="select pwd from user where username = ?" /> 
               <!-- for encrypt pwd <property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder" />  -->
            </bean>

        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<!--
This bean defines the security roles for the Services Management application.  Simple deployments can use the in-memory version.
More robust deployments will want to use another option, such as the Jdbc version.

The name of this should remain "userDetailsService" in order for Spring Security to find it.
 -->
<!-- <sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />-->

<sec:user-service id="userDetailsService">
    <sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</sec:user-service>
<!-- yyz add for supportting DB DataSource -->
<bean id="casDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>  
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</value></property>      
    <property name="username"><value>test</value></property>  
    <property name="password"> <value>test</value></property>  
</bean>  
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">  
    <property name="driverClassName"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>  
    <property name="url"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/test</value></property>      
    <property name="username"><value>test</value></property>  
    <property name="password"> <value>test</value></property>  
</bean>  
<!-- 无 <bean class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.Md5PasswordEncoder" /> MD5-->
<bean id="passwordEncoder" class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder">
  <constructor-arg index="0" value="SHA" />
</bean>
<!-- end by yyz -->
<!-- yyz comment :- http://www.blogjava.net/tufanshu/archive/2011/01/21/343290.html 
        :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882298/getting-more-attributes-from-cas-than-just-user-id 
Bean that defines the attributes that a service may return.  This example uses the Stub/Mock version.  A real implementation
may go against a database or LDAP server.  The id should remain "attributeRepository" though.
<bean id="attributeRepository"
    class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.StubPersonAttributeDao">
    <property name="backingMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="uid" value="uid" />
            <entry key="eduPersonAffiliation" value="eduPersonAffiliation" /> 
            <entry key="groupMembership" value="groupMembership" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean> -->
<bean id="attributeRepository" class="org.jasig.services.persondir.support.jdbc.SingleRowJdbcPersonAttributeDao">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="casDataSource" />
    <!-- <constructor-arg index="1" value="select id as UId, pwd as ph from user where username=?" /> -->
    <constructor-arg index="1" value="select * from user where {0}" />
    <property name="queryAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="username" value="username"/                              </map>
    </property>
    <property name="resultAttributeMapping">
        <map>
            <entry key="id" value="uid" />          <entry key="pwd" value="ph" /> 
            <entry key="id" value="userid"/> -->
            <entry key="username" value="username"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean> 
<!-- commented by yyz according to: https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Configuring
Sample, in-memory data store for the ServiceRegistry. A real implementation
would probably want to replace this with the JPA-backed ServiceRegistry DAO
The name of this bean should remain "serviceRegistryDao".-->

<bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.InMemoryServiceRegistryDaoImpl">
        <property name="registeredServices">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
                    <property name="id" value="0" />
                    <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP" />
                    <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols" />
                    <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://.*" />
                    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="10000001" />
                </bean>
                <!--
                Use the following definition instead of the above to further restrict access
                to services within your domain (including subdomains).
                Note that example.com must be replaced with the domain you wish to permit.
                -->
                <!--
                <bean class="org.jasig.cas.services.RegexRegisteredService">
                    <property name="id" value="1" />
                    <property name="name" value="HTTP and IMAP on example.com" />
                    <property name="description" value="Allows HTTP(S) and IMAP(S) protocols on example.com" />
                    <property name="serviceId" value="^(https?|imaps?)://([A-Za-z0-9_-]+\.)*example\.com/.*" />
                    <property name="evaluationOrder" value="0" />
                </bean>
                -->
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
 <!-- yyz added to replace the above - - >
<bean id="serviceRegistryDao" class="org.jasig.cas.services.JpaServiceRegistryDaoImpl"   
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />  
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>        
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">            
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">                
            <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>                
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />            
        </bean>        
    </property>        
    <property name="jpaProperties">            
        <props>                
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect</prop>                
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>            
        </props>        
    </property>    
</bean>     
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">        
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>    
</bean>     
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
< ! - - yyz added end -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your service ticket fails validation because there is an error in your configuration such that the host names are different in the serviceIds.  If you look at the log entry:

```
[http://yeyz-pc:8080/grsp/shiro-cas does not match supplied service [http:// yeyc-pc:8080/grsp/shiro-cas]
```

The first host is: yeyz-pc
The second host is: yeyc-pc

One host has a "z" and one has a "c".

Comment: How can I say to thank you. Thanks very much. And I think I am tired now and need some rest... Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In recent configuration of deployerConfigContext.xml, no one is granted to access /cas/services. So the message of "access denied:UsernameNotFoundException::y2" appear.
Change

```
<sec:user-service id="userDetailsService">
<sec:user name="@@THIS SHOULD BE REPLACED@@" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

to

```
<sec:user-service id="userDetailsService">
<sec:user name="y2" password="notused" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

This means that y2 is granted as ROLE_ADMIN to access /cas/services which is protected with CAS itself.